# Actualizar valor de una props para hacer un buscador

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue3, composition-api

Estoy tratando de actualizar una tabla dinámica a la hora de escribir un parámetro por el cual quiero buscar un registro.

Primeramente tengo un formulario (componente Padre) y dos tablas (componentes hijos). Cuando hago clic en el botón de buscar de mi formulario, la tabla se llena de registros perfectamente. El problema es cuando en mi input de búsqueda por nombre, escribo el nombre por el cual necesito buscar. No me devuelve en la consola ningún error, en la pestaña de network veo que se hacen las peticiones a la API perfectamente y esta devuelve los datos necesarios pero no consigo actualizar mi tabla para mostrar esos datos únicamente, no se actualiza el valor de mi prop. Para hacer toda esta lógica, en mi componente padre formulario, tengo:

Por cierto estoy trabajando con VUE 3 y composition API.

```
const registers = ref([])
```

En la llamada a mi función para buscar los registros:

```
registers.value =  response.data.data
```

Y cuando incluyo mi componente tabla (hijo 1) le envío esos datos:

```
<nAsignedCalls :valor="registers" ...>
```

En este componente tengo definida mi `prop` `valor` y por medio de un `v-for` lleno la tabla

```
const props = defineProps({
        valor: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        },
     ...............
```

Posteriormente tengo un input con una llamada a la función para buscar:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
   <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control searchName" placeholder="Nombre" @keyup="searchName('name')">
</div>
```

Y mi función `searchName()`

```
const queryForKeywords = async (event) => {
        const response = await axios.get(`/api/listingApi/show?page=${1}`, { params: { 'searchParams': event } }) 
        //emit('update:valor', await JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data)));
        props.valor.value = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data));

        console.log(props.valor.value)
    };


    const searchName = (action) => {
        let value = document.getElementsByClassName('searchName')[0].value
        const params = [action, value];
        
        queryForKeywords(params)
    }
```

Todo esta lógica hasta la parte de buscar me está funcionando perfectamente. Pero la función de buscar, no me actualiza la tabla, este `console.log(props.valor.value)` me está devolviendo los datos bien también... Pero no sé qué me falta para poder actualizar mi tabla y mostrar únicamente el/los registros que estoy buscando. He tratado también de crear un evento personalizado, se puede ver en mi código comentado. Pero obtengo el mismo resultado.

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente, como no he conseguido respuesta y tampoco conseguía sacarlo. He decidido hacer una función para buscar dentro de mi tabla los valores que hay.

```
const searchName = (event) => {
        
        var filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
        filter = event.target.value;
        table = document.getElementById("assignedRegisters");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
            if (td) {
                txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                if (txtValue.indexOf(filter) != -1) {
                    console.log("entro -> "+txtValue);
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    console.log("aqui -> "+txtValue);
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }    
        }
    }
```

De esta manera ya puedo filtrar por nombre en mi tabla y si borro el contenido del input, no pierdo los valores anteriores.